# Appending To List<string>

Tags: c#, arrays, sqldatareader

Using `C#` how can I append to a `List<string>`?  I am wanting to run two seperate SQL Queries and store the results of both in my `List<string>`.  The first query returns

> Bill and Joe

And the second query returns

> James and Charles

But my `Console.WriteLine()` only produces `Bill` and `Joe`

What did I set-up improperly in my syntax for this to occur?

```
public static List<string> tempList = new List<string>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{   
  string qs = "Select Top 2 firstname from thistable";
  //
  GetFirstSetOfData(qs);

  string bc = "Select Top 2 firstname from thattable";
  //
  GetFirstSetOfData(bc);

  foreach (string tumble in tempList)
    Console.WriteLine(tumble);
}

private static void GetFirstSetOfData(string query)
{
  connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
  {
    cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    connection.Open();
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
        tempList.Add(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
    reader.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't compile since `GetFirstSetOfData` can't access tempList. In your actual code, how is `tempList` defined?

Comment: Sorry it's a class variable.  Let me fix that real quick.

Comment: Thanks. As the code stands, this should work. `tempList` is instantiated only once, and since it's a reference type, both calls to GetFirstSetOfData append to the same list instance. This is assuming that `thattable` actually returns the results you think it does. You can try `while (reader.Read()) { var x = reader.GetValue(0).ToString(); Console.WriteLine(x); tempList.Add(x); }` to verify that the query is returning what you expect.

Comment: (Unrelated to the issue, there are some recommendations about the code itself, e.g., use `using` around disposables like connection and reader, but that's unrelated to the issue you're asking about)

Comment: You should also try to isolate the method. let the `GetFirstSetOfData` return a list to the main method and do the add there

Comment: @MichaelStum - good call, I didn't think about adding in a using block OR checking if reader was null.

Comment: All good advices but your code should work if the second table has two rows. How did you check that the method reads effectively _James_ and _Charles_?

Comment: @Steve - ran the syntax in SSMS

Comment: @StarsFlyFreeFromCozyNights FWIW, reader would never be null. `cmd.ExecuteReader` will either throw an exception or return a reader.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it probably has something to do with the SQLConnection. It would be better to initialize the SQLConnection in your Main method instead of trying to connect to the same database a second time. Also, the SQLConnection should really be disposed of once you're done. The easy way to make sure that happens is to wrap things in a `using` statement, like so:

```
using (connection = new SQLConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    //do all your queries and things
}
```

You can see an excellent full example on MSDN here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.close(v=vs.110).aspx

Try that and see if it works. I think the problem is that you're trying connection.open twice on the same connection. Could be wrong though, its been a while since I messed with sql in c#.

Comment: If there is something wrong with the connection he should see an exception at the Open call. Good advice about the using statement but this cannot be the problem with the code posted.

Comment: Ok, didn't rember if that one would throw an error or not. However, some environments, particularly web servers, tend to suppress errors silently. So if He's running it through visual studio he would already know if it were a problem with the open statement, otherwise he ought to do something to confirm that his code is getting past that second call.